# How do I concat wstrings?

Tags: c++11

I want to use the following code:

```
wstring s = L"GetLockCount " + g_SpeakerAlias.c_str();
MessageBoxW(NULL, unsignedinttowstring(iLockCount).c_str(), s, MB_OK);
```

The compiler tells me:

```
The expression must have an integer enumeration type or an enumeration type without range restriction
```

The way I try to concat the 2 wstrings seems to be wrong:

```
L"GetLockCount " + g_SpeakerAlias.c_str()
```

Here is the declaration:

```
wstring  g_SpeakerAlias=L"SomeName";
```

Comment: Notice that instead of `unsignedinttowstring` you can use `std::to_wstring`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .c_str() is not necessary for the concatenation.
You need it only in the MessageBoxW as it expects LPCWSTR.

This is correct:

```
wstring s = L"GetLockCount " + g_SpeakerAlias;
MessageBoxW(NULL, unsignedinttowstring(iLockCount).c_str(), s.c_str(), MB_OK);
```

To be clear, the reason this works is because, while L"GetLockCount " is not a wstring (it's a wide-character C-style string literal, which is not a C++ wstring), g_SpeakerAlias is a wstring, and an overload exists for operator+ where the left side is a wchar_t* and the right is a wstring that produces another wstring. When you call .c_str(), it fails, because there is no overload covering wchar_t* + wchar_t*. Another solution would be to do wstring s = L"GetLockCount ";, then follow up with s += g_SpeakerAlias;; wstring constructs from the literal, then concats.

Comment: To be clear, the reason this works is because, while `L"GetLockCount "` is not a `wstring` (it's a wide-character C-style string literal, which is not a C++ `wstring`), `g_SpeakerAlias` is a `wstring`, and an overload exists for `operator+` where the left side is a `wchar_t*` and the right is a `wstring` that produces another `wstring`. When you call `.c_str()`, it fails, because there is no overload covering `wchar_t* + wchar_t*`. Another solution would be to do `wstring s = L"GetLockCount ";`, then follow up with `s += g_SpeakerAlias;`; `wstring` constructs from the literal, *then* concats.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Would you allow me to insert your comment into my answer? Or if not, you can gladly post your comment as the answer.

Comment: Go ahead and add it in. Keep what you like, rephrase, whatever; important part is the OP knows why it didn't work, and why the change makes it work, so they can solve the problem in the future by logic, rather than cargo cult programming.